# Why is $PATH in ruby Shell Different than $PATH in Term?

Tags: ruby, shell, terminal

Why is `PATH` in ruby executed `Shell` Different than path in the Term? And how do I make them eqv?

```
puts %x[echo $SHELL]
puts %x[echo $PATH].split(':').length
```

returns

```
/bin/bash
8
```

but in shell:

```
/bin/bash
13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely because the shell started by `%x` does not source your profile (it is not a login shell). If that's the case, then you can do

```
puts %x[bash --login -c 'echo $PATH']
```

Comment: how do I make it eqv? or load my profile into the ruby %x shell?

Comment: @Mr.DemetriusMichael, I was updating my answer just as you were writing your comment

Comment: looks great, but when I `puts %x[bash --login -c 'echo $PATH'; wget www.google.com]` it gives me the error: `sh: wget: command not found` (wget is in my profile, not login shell)

Comment: put your whole script inside the single quotes so it gets executed in the same login shell: `puts %x[bash --login -c 'echo $PATH; wget www.google.com']`